# What Would Be a Word to Mean "Suggest the expectation of (something)"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if someone makes a comment such as: "*I hope your journey back went well*", there is an implication that a response is expected even if a question wasn't directly asked. The sort of context I am thinking of would be:

> *Her comment elicited a response.*

or

> *Her comment incited a response.*

Neither is quite satisfactory as the former suggests as response was actually given (which may not be the case and the latter has connotations of violence or unpleasantness. However, I hope the sort of intention is clear.

Another example might be:

> *His warning look [indicated the expectation of] agreement.*

I realise this is a very specific question but I am sure there is a word for this!

Other words I have thought of but don't quite match what I am thinking of:

*Necessitated* or *Behoved*.

Comment: It seems to me that to "suggest an expectation" is to "promise".

Comment: I would use ***invited*** or ***awaited*** for the first sample sentence, and ***demanded*** for the second. Do you expect a single word that would work for both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Her comment "**invited**" a response.

(Perhaps what was at the back of your mind when you wrote "incited a response"?)

Comment: Invited fits this context best I think. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

***Invited*** *a response* seems like a good option to me, but exploring farther for connotations in the semantic field:

***welcomed***--very similar to invted

***suggested***--a bit more subtle with an added aspect of leading toward a specific reply

***proposed***--a bit more formal

***summoned***--a bit more forceful

***invoked*** or ***urged***--even more forceful

***commanded***, ***compelled*** or ***demanded***--close to the top of the force meter

***begged***--emphasizes the obviousness, or importunity

***inveigled***--implies deception or trickery

***lured***--an element of enticement

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for **"prompted"**

"Her comment prompted him to explain what he had done."

prompt someone to/to do something - cause someone to take a course of action [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prompt)

Depending on the comment, you might say **"triggered"**

- "Certain foods trigger headaches."
- "His remarks triggered a public reaction."
- "The Prime Minister's remarks triggered bitter debates."

Answer (score 1):

"Her comment [*anticipated*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/anticipate) a response".

Answer (score 0):

To [imply](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Imply) may fit the context:

> - to express or indicate by a hint; suggest.

Her comment implied a response.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps "...invited a response",  "anticipated a response", or "assumed a response"; or something along the lines of:

- Frederick's action was accommodating /  inspired a response / necessitated reply ...
- Elucidating my reaction with his/her action ...
- It was obligatory that I offer an explanation, the question was clearly suggested by...
- her necklace demanded I tell her everything about my trip to tahiti.

Comment: What's the stream-of-consciousness paragraph for?  I'm not really getting anything that remotely answers the OP's question in that block...